# Appscript Deployment Not running Macros

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, web-applications

I was given a spreadsheet with app scrip macros that we would like to use from a friend.

The purpose of the spreadsheet is to display datetime for follow ups over certain time periods(i.e. in 2 weeks or in 8 hours) in different time zones(PST/MST/CST/EST). All of the macro files in the appscript look good and the manifest file also looks right but when I deploy it doesn't update any of the cells in the sheets. If i run the individual macros they update the cell in the sheet that its supposed to. It is supposed to continuously update the date times to current time or at least on sheet open.

I'm new to google app script but have an ok coding background and I feel like this should be something simple. I may be missing a run file or a call to run but im not sure where that should be added. Can add any other relevant info if needed.

JSON Manifest file sample:

````
{
  "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "FollowupTagfilterforBCTeam",
        "libraryId": "186UPce75w8KpinMaHxLVgk494S7nthWonp-Iruh_Yo0PsnXqWb2qtBrl",
        "version": "0",
        "developmentMode": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  },
  "sheets": {
    "macros": [
      {
        "menuName": "updateCSTTime10days",
        "functionName": "updateCSTTime10days"
      },```
````

Macro File sample for above:

```
function updateCSTTime10days() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CST");
  var cstTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (240 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // Adding 240 hours     for CST
  var formattedDate = cstTime.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Chicago", year:     'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-    digit'});
  sheet.getRange("B6").setValue(formattedDate);
}
```

Tried running individually and the macros work.
Tried doing triggers but there are hundreds and started to fail some on open(also think there is a smarter way to call them all rather than a trigger for each)
Tested different deployments and made sure the library lined up

Comment: Did you copy them to a script file and try to run some dummy program that does nothing just to get the authentication?  Also if they're store in a library then to run them you will need to add the name of the library as well.

Comment: All of the macros have their own .gs file. Do you mean put the library to each macro .gs file? Each function is in the manifest and the library is as well not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I don't put functions in the manifest and generally I have a lot of functions in each file.  Basically they are all accessiable as long as they have unique names.  Do all of your function have function declarations? And have you tried to run  one of them just to get the container to check scopes and give you an opportunity to authenticate them.

Comment: What is this for? `"sheets": {
    "macros": [
      {
        "menuName": "updateCSTTime10days",
        "functionName": "updateCSTTime10days"
      }`

Comment: The manifest was written by someone else so trying to decode it to understand the point of it tbh. I have authenticated the macros and they work when ran individually, they update the times in the spread sheets as expected. 

Your other comment in the manifest it follows that pattern for all the macro files. I can drop the full code if needed. A bit new on StackOverflow for posting, can I add the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by creating a few new scripts, took a bit of learning but one added a button that will execute all macros and the other is a onOpen timebased trigger that will run all macros every minute until the sheet is closed.